# Rails spec error: expected valid? to return true, got false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm following Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, but got the following error when testing out my code. I can't seem to figure out why my object does not pass as valid.

My user.rb-file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

and here is my user_rspec.rb:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com")  }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " "}

    it { should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " "}

    it { should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51}

    it { should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example-user@foo.]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do 
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do

    before do
      user_with_same_email =  @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it {should_not be_valid}

  end

end
```

When I run my test I get the following error:
    Failures:

```
  1) User 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21355 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:12 # User `
```

When I run user_with_same_email.errors in my rails console I get the following answer:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :001 > user = User.new(name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at:     nil> 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :002 > user_with_same_email =  user.dup
 => #<User id: nil, name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :003 > user_with_same_email.valid?
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") =     LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
 => true 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :004 > user_with_same_email.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fad6491f780 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "bobo", email:    "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}> 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :005 >
```

As you can see the error does not pass any message.

Does anybody know how I can fix this error?

Thanks!

Added:

The error seems to appear when I try to save a user with an email that is already saved.

```
$ rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.0)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :001 > user = User.new(name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at:         nil> 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :002 > user.save
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") =     LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES       (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 16 Oct 2013 10:15:19 UTC +00:00], ["email",     "user@example.com"], ["name", "bobo"], ["updated_at", Wed, 16 Oct 2013 10:15:19 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true 
    ruby-2.0.0-p247 :003 > user_with_same_email =  user.dup
 => #<User id: nil, name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :004 > user_with_same_email.save
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => false 
ruby-2.0.0-p247 :005 >
```

I'm not sure really why this happens. Shouldn't my validations take care of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try doing the test in the console manually and then check the value of `user.errors`

Comment: Still somewhat of a rookie; How do I check the value of user.errors?

Comment: Open a console `rails c`, type `user = User.new(name: "bobo", email: "user@example.com")` (from your test above) and then `user.valid?` which will return false, then `user.errors` which will output the errors preventing the item from being valid.

Comment: Does anybody know what it is that I am missing? Been working on solving this on and off for a couple of days now, but for some reason there error persists.

Comment: isolate first:  remove the before_save - does it still give the error?  If so, try removing each of the 2 "validates" lines one by one and see if you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a name under 50 chars and your email is matched by the regex you made. The only thing left is uniqueness of the email. I bet you're not cleaning your DB properly between specs. Can you confirm by expanding your `should be_valid` spec to this?

```
it "is valid" do
  subject.valid?
  subject.errors.full_messages.should eq []
end
```

Calling `valid?` will populate the errors array, and then the spec will fail with the error messages.

If the email is already taken, then try using `database_cleaner` https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner#rspec-example (you'll have to add it to your `Gemfile` before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the error message via `@user.errors.messages` contains `{:email=>["has already been taken"]}`.

You may preliminarily solve this issue by adding to your **spec_helper.rb** ( in the `RSpec.configure do |config|`block) :

```
# clears user table
config.before(:suite) do
  User.destroy_all
end
```

But I'm not convinced with this solution. It seems, that the user won't destroy itself after the test case.

Answer (score 0):

my test also failed

```
  it { should be_Valid }
```

my rails console session (above) user.valid was true

corrected test below

```
it { should be_valid }
```

upper-case 'be_Valid' was the problem